# How to distinguish JavaScript Built-in Object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm currently learning JavaScript from ECMA [Manual](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1), and I'm confused with the concept of built-in object. I know that object like `Function`, `Object`, `Math` are built-in objects, and you can use them directly, e.g, `Math.PI`. But how about `var obj = new Function('return a')`, Can I call `obj` a built-in object? Or is it just a plain native object (but not built-in)? Thanks!

Edit: [Definition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.6) from ECMA

Comment: What is the difference between native and built-in for you? Either way, since you created `obj`, it's probably not a built-in object. It doesn't exist in another JS system.

Comment: Easy way to tell if its built in is if you log it and it returns "[native code]" in the function body, eg `String` returns  `function String() { [native code] }`

Comment: I got it, thanks you guys for clarify this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **[4.3.7](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.7) built-in object**
>
> object supplied by an ECMAScript implementation, independent of the
>   host environment, that is present at the start of the execution of an
>   ECMAScript program

You create the object `obj`. That means it wasn't present at the start of the execution of the ECMAScript program. Therefore, it isn't a built-in object.